# Pandas: drop certain values from a column with a string title

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

Say I have the following dataframe `df`:

```
        First C        Second C       Third C
0       0.104000       0.864000       -999
1       0.060337       0.812470       -999
2       0.065797       0.819570       0.802607
3       0.064715       0.817212       0.801755
```

I want to drop the first two lines because column `Third C` shows two weird values.

```
df = df.drop(df[df.('Third C') == -999].index)
```

This throws:

```
       df = df.drop(df[df.('Third C') == -999].index)
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And the same thing happens if I use `df.['Third C']` with square brackets. How can I perform this operation without having to rename my column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use only `[]` and remove `.`:

```
df = df.drop(df[df['Third C'] == -999].index)
```

But it is better to use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df['Third C'] != -999]
```

**Timings**:

The `drop` solution is slower, because it uses `boolean indexing` and `drop`:

```
In [204]: %timeit (df.drop(df[df['Third C'] == -999].index))
1000 loops, best of 3: 691 µs per loop

In [205]: %timeit (df[df['Third C'] != -999])
1000 loops, best of 3: 359 µs per loop
```

Comment: Yes, better to use boolean indexing.

Comment: In what sense is this better?

Comment: I think `boolean indexing` filter by mask, so drop is not necessary. First solution work, but is slowier.

Comment: No problem. Thank you for the very useful answer!